# Encrypting WCF message (net.msmq) when signing is specified

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

I'm using WCF to send a message via MSMQ (net.msmq protocol).  All is going well the BizTalk server receives the message and processes it.  However, when I looked into the SVCLOG, I see the message is encrypted when I specifically set MsmqProtectionLevel to Sign.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour?  Is it possible to stop the encryption?  Some of my messages are over 1MB and encryption makes things real slow.

Thanks in advance!

```
  ChannelFactory<OnRampEntry> Factory
  {
     get
     {
        if (factory == null)
        {
           lock (this)
           {
              if (factory == null)
              {
                 var uri = ResolveQueueName(new Uri(Url));
                 var identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(BizTalkIdentity);
                 var binding = new NetMsmqBinding(NetMsmqSecurityMode.Both)
                 {
                    DeadLetterQueue = DeadLetterQueue.System,
                    ExactlyOnce = true
                 };
                 binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
                 binding.Security.Transport.MsmqProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign;
                 binding.Security.Transport.MsmqAuthenticationMode = MsmqAuthenticationMode.WindowsDomain;
                 binding.Security.Transport.MsmqSecureHashAlgorithm = MsmqSecureHashAlgorithm.Sha1;
                 factory = new ChannelFactory<OnRampEntry>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri, identity, (AddressHeaderCollection) null));
                 factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new LogonCertificateBehavior());
                 factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.TrustedPeople, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, BizTalkIdentity);
                 factory.Open();
              }
           }
        }
        return factory;
     }
  }

  /// <summary>
  ///   MSMQ does not allow a DNS alias to be used in a queue name, e.g. "net.msmq://alias/private$/queue".
  ///   <b>ResolveQueueName</b> will tranlsate an alias to its actual machine name.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="uri"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  Uri ResolveQueueName(Uri uri)
  {
     var hostName = uri.DnsSafeHost;

     try
     {
        var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
        var resolved = new Uri(uri.ToString().Replace(hostName, hostEntry.HostName));

        if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
           log.Debug(string.Format("Resolved '{0}' to '{1}'.", uri, resolved));
        return resolved;
     }
     catch (SocketException e)
     {
        if (e.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.HostNotFound)
           return uri;
        throw e;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the message is encrypted is the use of the NetMsmqSecurityMode.Both - both transport and message security.

```
var binding = new NetMsmqBinding(NetMsmqSecurityMode.Both)
```

At the transport level, the configuration above uses

```
binding.Security.Transport.MsmqProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign;
```

Looking in WCF logs it will not be possible to see what is set at the transport level, as message level encryption is in place.

Unfortunately this does not answer the question of how to sign the message (with a X.509 certificate) without using the certificate to encrypt the body of the message.